# itextsharp postscript to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, postscript

Is it possible to use itextsharp to convert postscript to a PDF ? If not is there another way to do it in .net ?

Comment: GhostScript: yes.  You'll have to run it with a `system()` call and the proper command line arguments.  I'm not aware of an API to access it from another process (or to launch it within your own app's process for that matter).

Comment: Ghostscript's functionality is also available via a shared library. But then your own program  (a) either needs to fullfil the requirements of the GPLv3 license, or  (b) you'll need to acquire a commercial use license for Ghostscript from www.artifex.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting PostScript to PDF is called "distilling". iText and iTextSharp do not support distilling. Ghostscript will be your only FOSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ghostscript as it's explained here:

http://hi.baidu.com/lqyidxa_igfv/blog/item/df2037b394539fa0d9335a94.html